# Custom fonts won't render in Firefox for Rails 4 Application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, firefox, ruby-on-rails-4, custom-font

I've uploaded a custom font called Kodin, and all is working in IE, Chrome, and Safari but not in Firefox.

I've uploaded all custom fonts to app/assets/fonts

The files included are....

```
Kodin-Regular.otf
Kodin-Regular.eot
Kodin-Regular.woff
Kodin-Regular.ttf
```

My application.css file includes...

```
   @font-face {
        font-family: "KODIN";
        src: url('/assets/Kodin-Regular.otf') format("truetype");
        src: url('/assets/Kodin-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),  
          url('/assets/Kodin-Regular.woff') format('woff'),  
          url('/assets/Kodin-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');  
        font-weight: normal;  
        font-style: normal;  
    }
```

And all is fine. But the font isn't rendering ANYWHERE on the site in Firefox. I've seen a few stack overflow threads on how to resolve this, but none with Rails specific recommendations.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Found a few console errors in Firefox. Is the path incorrect?

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "KODIN" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/assets/Kodin-Regular.otf application.css:25:12
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "KODIN" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/assets/Kodin-Regular.woff application.css:25:12
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "KODIN" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:3): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/assets/Kodin-Regular.ttf application.css
```

Comment: maybe remove the first src: and add the url(otf) to the second src. i guess something gets overridden there!

Comment: Just gave it a try @DomlThe-Bread - all is okay in Chrome and Safari but it still isn't rendering in Firefox. Going to make an edit above because I see an error in the firefox console.

Comment: where is your css file located? and the fonts?

Comment: @DomlThe-Bread - css is dispersed in a variety of css files. The CSS displayed above for font-face is within the application.css.scss file - the fonts are under app/assets/fonts

Comment: since it is scss you might take a closer look to where the buildpath of your style.css is located and try to adjust your /assets/ path to the path **from** your __style.css__ file and not from the scss file. maybe you try it without the __/__ in the front `url('assets/Kodin-Regular)` but it is really interesting that the font gets rendered in the other browsers. the .woff file should be working in FF

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with .woff file - I'll look into that. Rails doesn't use a Style.css file - it disperses all of it's css into a variety of css files, then minifies them

Answer (score 1):

Try with asset-path as shown,hope it works.

```
src:url(asset-path('Kodin-Regular.otf')) format('truetype');
```

Comment: Just gave it a try. Not rendering still in Firefox but this still works for Chrome and Safari :(

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of putting this to the side I finally found the resolution.

My CSS is redundant, but I think Firefox requires its own @font-face for each asset you're calling...

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: "KODIN";
    src: url('/assets/KODIN-Regular.otf') format("truetype"),
      url('/assets/KODIN-Bold.otf') format("truetype"),
      url('/assets/KODIN-Light.otf') format("truetype"),
      url('/assets/KODIN-Medium.otf') format("truetype"),
      url('/assets/KODIN-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('/assets/KODIN-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
      url('/assets/KODIN-Regular.woff') format('woff'),  
      url('/assets/KODIN-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');  
    font-weight: normal;  
    font-style: normal;  
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "KODIN-bold";
    src:
      url('/assets/KODIN-Bold.otf') format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;  
    font-style: normal;  
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "KODIN-light";
    src:
      url('/assets/KODIN-light.otf') format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;  
    font-style: normal;  
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Kodin-light";
    src:
      url('/assets/KODIN-light.otf') format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;  
    font-style: normal;  
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "KODIN-medium";
    src:
      url('/assets/KODIN-medium.otf') format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;  
    font-style: normal;  
}
```

And when calling these fonts in the CSS, calling the fonts is case sensitive... case sensitive does not look to be an issue in Safari, IE or Chrome, but for some reason was an issue with firefox.